# Help determining what kind of network equipment I need

Tags: networking, router

I am trying to figure out what I need in order to complete my networking infrastructure. Here is the scenario I have:

I have a computer with a wireless networking adapter in it. My Internet comes from a wireless router located in my garage. Right now, what I do is I connect to the Internet using my wireless networking card. The router in the garage does NOT use DHCP, therefore, I must put in my specific IP address, `192.168.2.23`. My wireless network card connects just fine and I can get on the Internet.

Here is what I am trying to do. I need a piece of equipment, I'm thinking some kind of network bridge or something (this is the part I'm unsure of), that will wirelessly connect to my router in the garage (with the static IP address), then I would like to have the Internet re-routed to a router. The reason I need this is because I have a Voice-over-IP phone that my work gave me and it is not wireless. I need to connect it directly into a router to get it to work.

So what would I need in order to take my wireless internet and re-route through another physical router? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't the wireless router have any LAN ethernet ports?

Comment: Yes, but the wireless router is not near my computer. It is in my garage

Comment: Sorry, you did say that in your question.

Comment: is this really an appropriate question for serverfault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a wireless bridge... configured as a bridge, not a repeater.

Comment: I thought that. joeqwerty, is it possible you can link what it is I need, from like Tigerdirect or NewEgg or something?

Comment: Shopping recommendations are frowned upon here, but here you go: http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=wireless+bridge or http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/search.asp?keywords=wireless+bridge

Comment: Thanks. I just want to be sure I get the right thing. I won't necessarily buy from those links, rather, just use it as an example of what I need. Thanks again

Comment: Glad to help...